# Automation test in Ruby keep failing on CircleCI

Tags: ruby, automation, capybara, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a project with Automation tests for a Rails App. 
The project with the automated tests is a separate project from the Rails App that uses Capybara and headless Chrome to run the tests on CircleCI.

This is the config file:

```
module WaitForAjax
  def wait_for_ajax
    Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
      loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
    end
  end

  def finished_all_ajax_requests?
    page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include WaitForAjax, type: :feature
  config.before do
    Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
      options = {
        :js_errors => false,
          :debug => false,
          :phantomjs_options => ['--load-images=no', '--disk-cache=false'],
          :inspector => true
      }
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, options)
    end
    Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, desired_capabilities: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities
                                                                                         .chrome("chromeOptions" => { "args" => ["start-maximized"] }))
    end

    Capybara.register_driver :headless_chrome do |app|
      capabilities = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
        chromeOptions: { args: %w[headless disable-gpu] }
      )

      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new app,
        browser: :chrome,
        desired_capabilities: capabilities
    end

    Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5
    Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
    Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
  end
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.run_server = false
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium_chrome
  config.app_host = 'myapphost.com'
end
```

What currently happens is the on CircleCI and on my local machine when I run the whole test suite, some tests keep failing in a random manner without any apparent cause. If I run the tests file by file on my local machine, I do not encounter any issues.
I was wondering if anyone might know any solutions for this issue or debugging advice, I would highly appreciate it. 
Thanks a lot in advance.

UPDATE:

```
it 'should fill epay iframe form fields and finish transaction' do
  patient_id = DatabaseHelper.run_query(SQL_QUERIES['corral']['get_imported_patient'] % [@premium_practice_schema.to_s, @imported_patient_surname + ' ' + @imported_patient_name]).first[:id] # rubocop:disable Metrics/LineLength

  create_ach_transaction('today_amount': 100, 'total_amount': 500, 'patient_id': patient_id, 'payments_number': 2)

  expect(page.find(Patients::FIRST_PATIENT_BALANCE).text.gsub(/\$|\./, '').to_i).to eq 500 * 100
end
```

Error:

Failure/Error: expect(page.find(Patients::FIRST_PATIENT_BALANCE).text.gsub(/\$|./, '').to_i).to eq 500 * 100

```
   expected: 50000
        got: 10000
```

Comment: To clarify, the failures happen on your local machine as well as CircleCI?
Do they consistently fail on specific rspec seeds? What is the failure message?

Comment: Since it only fails when you run all the tests together it sounds like you have failures based on test order.  With the `seed` of a failing test run you can use the rspec `bisect` command - https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/command-line/bisect - to figure out what ordering causes the failure (there's also a minitest-bisect gem you can use if using minitest).  Adding the code of a failing test and the full exact error message returned to your question  would also help us have some idea as to possible causes.

Comment: Also it seems like the version of  Capybara you are using is probably obsolete since the line `config.app_host = 'myapphost.com'` should raise an error in any recent version telling you it needs to be a url (`http://myapphost.com`)

Comment: @ThomasWalpole the URL is ok, the real one is with https, so that is fine. I updated with a test and the error. I tried running the whole suite with bisect, but it did not ended with any conclusive results. I will give it a go by running it for a single file.

Comment: @BookOfGreg these failures happen on both my machine and on CircleCI when the entire suite is ran. For the seed part, my tests always run in the same order. The failure messages are mainly in the expectancy area or on elements that are not visible on the page.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're using expectations is defeating the waiting/retrying behavior built into the Capybara provided matchers in order to deal with dynamic pages.  I'm not completely sure this change will fix your current failure but it will decrease the amount of flaky tests (and remove the need for things like `wait_for_ajax`) going forward.  Basically, you should never be using the `eq` matcher for anything that deals with elements returned by Capybara.  Rather than

```
expect(page.find(Patients::FIRST_PATIENT_BALANCE).text.gsub(/\$|\./, '').to_i).to eq 500 * 100 .
```

which defeats waiting for the elements contents to change on a dynamic page (as well as being borderline unreadable as to what is actually being tested, and removing `.` from a money number is never a good idea when verifying accuracy), you should be writing it like

```
expect(page).to have_css(Patients::FIRST_PATIENT_BALANCE, exact_text: "$500.00") # or whatever the total is supposed to be as shown on the page
```

That assumes `Patients::FIRST_PATIENT_BALANCE` is a CSS selector, if it's an XPath expression use `have_xpath` instead. That could also be written as

```
expect(find(Patients::FIRST_PATIENT_BALANCE)).to have_text("$500.00", exact: true)
```

if desired, or if you already had a reference to the FIRST_PATIENT_BALANCE element.

Comment: I will give a try and see where it leads me. Thanks!